# Merge Account tab with Menu tab in mobile menu

Tags: magento2, menu, navigation

New to Magento. I am trying to merge the content of the two default tabs on mobile view into one tab. Is it possible to add store.links (Account) as a link in the store.menu (Menu) much like the Industries link?

[image]

Comment: Did you find anything? I want to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with simple JS and css code.
In Magento Account links are added to Account tab using this piece of code in vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js

```
$('.panel.header > .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.links');
```

You can override theme.js file in your custom theme and change the code to

```
$('.panel.header > .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.menu');
```

So the account links are now available in Menu Tab.
To remove the tab like structure you can add this css code

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.nav-sections .nav-sections-item-title {
    display: none;
}
.nav-sections-item-content {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
}
```

Menu tab is by default active.